# Swift camera issue

Tags: ios, swift3, camera, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a `UIView` that works as camera and it's 320x180 and a `UIImageView` of same size.

When I take a photo, it generates me an `UIImage` of size 1080x1920, so when I show it on the `imageView`, what happens is that the photo is very compressed on its height, because it is very tall, is like this

```
██████    the black rectangle is the whole photo (1080x1920)
██████
█▒▒▒▒█    the gray is what camera show in screen
██████    (it shows only gray part but it stores
██████     all the black part 1080x1920)
```

I would like to store it as an UIImage exactly how I see it on the gray rectangle.

I'm not sure how to do this, since the size of the photo is way bigger than the resolution the screen (which is 320 x 568) so is hard to crop correctly (and the crop is also rotating the image and bringing other bugs).

Answer (score 0):

1080/6 = 180. 1920/6 = 320. So the values are in the correct aspect ratio — but they are reversed. You need to apply the correct rotation value to the image.